# ReadOnlyNameValueCollection (reading from ConfigurationManager.GetSection)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, types, configurationmanager

Ok, so.....

```
<section name="test" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler" />
<test>
   <add key="foo" value="bar" />
</test>

var test = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("test");
```

So far so good. The debugger shows `test` contains one key, `foo`.

But `GetSection` returns `object`, so we need a cast:

```
var type = test.GetType();
// FullName: System.Configuration.ReadOnlyNameValueCollection
// Assembly: System
```

Ok, this should be simple enough. So....

```
using System;

var test = ConfigurationManager
               .GetSection("test") as ReadOnlyNameValueCollection;
```

error!

`The type or namespace ReadOnlyNameValueCollection does not exist in the namespace System.Configuration. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

err... wtf?

A cast to `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` gets the code working, but I don't really understand why the error.

And a search for `ReadOnlyNameValueCollection` on MSDN shows there is no documentation on this class at all. It doesn't seem to exist. Yet I have an instance of that type in my code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`System.Configuration.ReadOnlyNameValueCollection` is an `internal` class to the System.dll assembly. So you can't refer to it from your code. It derives from `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`, though, so that's why you're able to do that with the cast.

Comment: Ok well that makes sense. But then why are they returning an internal class from a public method? And then not providing any documentation? Is this not considered bad practice? Under what circumstance would you want to do this?

Comment: It does seem a tad odd but the return type of the function is actually `object` so its not like they're exposing the internal type directly (which wouldn't even compile, I don't believe). And since it derives from a public type, you can make use of the object. From what I can tell, the point of `GetSection` is that you know when you mkae the call to it what you're expecting to get out of it. So as long as there's *something* for it to cast to that's valid, it seems reasonable. 
I liken it to return an internal derived type when the return type is really the base type. No problems there, right?

Comment: You can access members (e.g. Keys) using `dynamic` keyword.